# Position function of Mathematica in Excel for matrix lookup by value

Tags: excel, lookup, vba

I have a table in Excel with column and row headers and corresponding values. How do I lookup in Excel both the column and row header names/index by value in the table?

In Mathematica the equivalent function is Position[listoflist,value]

EDIT:

---

I made a simple function in VBA, but this is far from perfect

```
Function MathematicaPosition(lookvalue As Range, TableRange As Range, RowOrColumn As Boolean) As Integer
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim tempindex As Integer
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

tempindex = 0
r = TableRange.Rows.Count
c = TableRange.Columns.Count
For i = 1 To r
    For j = 1 To c 
        If lookvalue.Value = TableRange.Cells(i, j).Value Then
            tempindex = IIf(RowOrColumn, i, j)
        End If
    Next j
Next i
MathematicaPosition = tempindex
End Function
```

Comment: Why the Mathematica tag was removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function MathematicaPosition(lookvalue As Range, TableRange As Range, RowOrColumn As Boolean) As Integer
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim tempindex As Integer
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

tempindex = 0
r = TableRange.Rows.Count
c = TableRange.Columns.Count
For i = 1 To r
    For j = 1 To c 
        If lookvalue.Value = TableRange.Cells(i, j).Value Then
            tempindex = IIf(RowOrColumn, i, j)
        End If
    Next j
Next i
MathematicaPosition = tempindex
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

See the double lookup section here:

http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/TablesAndLookups.aspx

Comment: Double lookup does reverse. I need indices of column and row based on value in table.

Answer (score 0):

**Lifted direct from [MrExcel](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/345657-reverse-two-way-lookup-2.html)**

Assuming data array is in A1:D5:

In G2: `=COUNTIF(B2:D5,G1)`

In G4: `=IF(ROWS($G$4:G4)>$G$2,"",INDEX($A$2:$A$5,INT(SMALL(IF($B$2:$D$5=$G$1,(ROW($B$2:$D$5)-ROW($B$2)+1)*10^5+COLUMN($B$2:$D$5)-COLUMN($B$2)+1),ROWS($G$4:G4))/10^5)))`

In H4: `=IF(ROWS($G$4:G4)>$G$2,"",INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MOD(SMALL(IF($B$2:$D$5=$G$1,(ROW($B$2:$D$5)-ROW($B$2)+1)*10^5+COLUMN($B$2:$D$5)-COLUMN($B$2)+1),ROWS($G$4:G4)),10^5)))`

The latter two entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and copied down.

I have no idea about Mathematica and don't understand `reverse values` (basically whether to multiply by -1 or switch columns over).

Comment: this uses array formulas, which are very clumsy for large dataset manipulation. Also the formula looks unreadable and not generalized.

Comment: Why do you have 10^5 multiplier in the formula?