# Enter number into a cell and search an array for that number using a 2D range

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am reconciling accounts and was wondering if there is a formula/VBA I can use to search for certain values, as the find function doesn't work?

For example: enter `-54.12` into a cell, formula/VBA searches an array for that number.

This may explain better what I'm trying to achieve, albeit more of an explanation than coding:

```
Sub Test()

Dim Value As Integer
Dim Account As Range
Dim Lookup As Boolean

Value = Range("D8")
Account = Range("E:E")

Set Value = A
Set Account = B
' IF A is present in B then look up = true
' if look up is true then scroll to cell

End Sub
```

I could then set a Private Sub by value change to do the same thing each time a new value is entered?

Comment: `MATCH` will return the relative position of the number in the array, or #N/A if not found.  Is that what you want?

Comment: I have tried to use MATCH but it keeps returning #N/A I tried a test of a 4x4 array containing a number i was searching for only to receive #N/A

Comment: ah.  `MATCH` only works with 1D ranges.  So are you looking for an equivalent of `MATCH` that works for 2D ranges?  I suggest editing that into your question.

Comment: [this thread has two good solutions](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/516742-how-return-results-position-2d-array.html).  I don't have time to write up an answer, so free rep for anyone who does!

Comment: You use MATCH for the x axis, and then another MATCH for the y axis. Used in conjunction with INDEX, as follows, where column A contains a list of items where you want to match "foo", and row 1 contains a list of items where you want to match "bar": '=INDEX(A1:D10,MATCH("foo",A1:A10,0),MATCH("bar",A1:D1,0))'

Comment: what kind of return are you aiming at? what if there are many matches? please show your data so we can indicate exactly what to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lifted directly from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19126873/1505120 (where I forgot to mention the search term goes in G1):

**Lifted direct from [MrExcel](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/345657-reverse-two-way-lookup-2.html)**

Assuming data array is in A1:D5:

In G2: `=COUNTIF(B2:D5,G1)`

In G4: `=IF(ROWS($G$4:G4)>$G$2,"",INDEX($A$2:$A$5,INT(SMALL(IF($B$2:$D$5=$G$1,(ROW($B$2:$D$5)-ROW($B$2)+1)*10^5+COLUMN($B$2:$D$5)-COLUMN($B$2)+1),ROWS($G$4:G4))/10^5)))`

In H4: `=IF(ROWS($G$4:G4)>$G$2,"",INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MOD(SMALL(IF($B$2:$D$5=$G$1,(ROW($B$2:$D$5)-ROW($B$2)+1)*10^5+COLUMN($B$2:$D$5)-COLUMN($B$2)+1),ROWS($G$4:G4)),10^5)))`

The latter two entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and copied down.